# datastore use BlobKey to download

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

In the google appengine datastore, there is a BlobKey (labled as csv).  The key is in the following format: `encoded_gs_file:we1o5o7klkllfekomvcndhs345uh5pl31l`.  I would like to provide a download button to save this information.  My question is, what is the endpoint that i can use to access this.  More information about the BlobKey is below.

[image]

The web app is being run using `dev_appserver.py` and uses python 2.7 (Django) as the backend.  Currently, a button exists, but when clicking on it, it returns a 404 error.  The download link that the button provides is:

```
    https://localhost:8080/data?key=encoded_gs_file:dwndjndwamwljioihkm
```

[image]

My question is, how can i use the blobkey to generate a url that can be downloaded; or how can i check my code base to find how the url that i can use is being generated?

```
class BlobstoreDataServer(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self):
        k = str(urllib.unquote(self.request.params.get('key','')))
        logging.debug(k)
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(k)
        logging.debug(blob_info)
        if (not blob_info) or (not blob_info.size):
            self.error(404)
            return
        self.response.headers['X-Blob-Size'] = str(blob_info.size)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = blob_info.content_type
        self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = (u'attachment; filename=%s' % blob_info.filename).encode('utf-8')
        self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

Edit: New Images
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a Request Handler for the route `/data` that does something like this?

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

class DisplayBlob(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):

    def get(self):
        blob_key = self.request.GET['key']

        self.send_blob(ndb.BlobKey(blob_key))

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
```

**EDIT:**

Ok so the `404` is probably being thrown by you by this line: `self.error(404)` right? Add a `logging.warn('BlobstoreDataServer is throwing 404')` right before to make sure. Also are you seeing this line `logging.debug(k)` print (I want to confirm that `BlobstoreDataServer` is even getting hit)? You may need to do `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` to see it.

So that means `blobstore.BlobInfo.get(k)` is returning `None`. Focus on making sure that is working first, you can do this in the interactive console.

1. Go to http://localhost:8000/blobstore

[image]

2. Open one of them and copy the Key (`encoded_gs_file:dwndjndwamwljioih...`)

[image]

3. Go to the Interactive console (http://localhost:8000/console) and enter this code and hit 'EXECUTE' and make sure it is able to find it:

[image]

If that step didn't work, then then something is up with your `dev_appserver.py`'s blobstore emulator

4. If that works, then just manually paste that same key at the end of your download link:
   `https://localhost:8080/data?key=<paste_encoded_gs_file_key_here>`

If this step didn't work then something is up with your download handler, maybe this line is transforming the key somehow `str(urllib.unquote(self.request.params.get('key','')))`

If this step worked then something is up with your code that generates this link `https://localhost:8080/data?key=...`, maybe you're actually writing to a different `gcs_filename` than what you are constructing a different `BlobKey` for.

Comment: hey alex, thanks i added the BlobStoreDownloadHandler

Comment: hey alex, thanks for the walk-through. It has been such a learning experience. You are right, the problem is that `blob_info = none`. The interesting thing is that, when i go to localhost:8000/datastore  and then navigate to the Blobstore Viewer, the blob key does not even exist.   However, when i go to `localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore`, i can navigate to Entity Kind: `__GsFileInfo__`, there is the key i need.  It is strange it says that creation=None, finalized=False.  I have attached images below; thank you!